# Unexpected <EOF>: Can a graphql file only import other files and do nothing else?

Tags: graphql, apollo, prisma, graphql-tag

I am using `apollo-server-express` to run my GraphQL server with a prisma database. My main schema is listed below, which just uses `graphql-tag/loader` to import other `.graphql` files. When I try to run my server locally, I get the following message:

> Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/graphql-tag/loader.js):
>   GraphQLError: Syntax Error: Unexpected

Clearly, GraphQL wants `schema/schema.graphql` to declare some types, etc. Is there a way I can get around this so that I can have a `.graphql` file that all it does is import other `.graphql` files?

**schema/schema.graphql:**

```
#import '../generated/prisma.graphql'
#import './secondSchema.graphql'
```

**index.js:**

```
import http from 'http';
import express from 'express';
import { ApolloServer } from 'apollo-server-express';
import resolvers from './schema/resolvers';
import schema from './schema/schema.graphql';
import prisma from './prisma';

const server = new ApolloServer({
  context: {
    prisma,
  },
  resolvers,
  typeDefs: schema,
});

const app = express();
server.applyMiddleware({ app });

const PORT = 5000;

const httpServer = http.createServer(app);
server.installSubscriptionHandlers(httpServer);

httpServer.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server ready at http://localhost:${PORT}${server.graphqlPath}`);
  console.log(`Subscriptions ready at ws://localhost:${PORT}${server.subscriptionsPath}`);
});

if (module.hot) {
  module.hot.accept();
  module.hot.dispose(() => server.stop());
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a "dummy" or placeholder type that's not actually used anywhere so that the parser doesn't complain. However, the simpler fix would be to stop importing the other type definition files into one file and just pass all of them to `typeDefs` as an array.

```
const server = new ApolloServer({
  context: {
    prisma,
  },
  resolvers,
  typeDefs: [prismaTypeDefs, someOtherTypeDefs],
});
```